# How can I sort a map according to a property of its values?

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I've created a map having a vector as below:

```
map<int,vector<int>> mymap;
```

How can I sort this map according to the *n*<sup>th</sup> value of the vector contained by map?

Comment: You can't. An `std::map` is sorted according to its keys.

Comment: Yes you can. You should be able to provide a comparer as third type to the map declaration. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ However getting the value might be tricky or rather impossible.

Comment: I've to agree with @juanchopanza since the comparator only worries about the `Key` and not the `Value` part of the inserted element and thus it isn't possible. Btw, I +1'd _Yes you can_ to realize it's wrong :(

Comment: @Samuel So you can but it  might be impossible? Interesting definition of "can".

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: So, instead of a map, would using a vector as below change the state of the problem?

<i> vector<pair<int,vector<int>>> winner; </i>

Comment: @user3744394: That depends. What is the problem?

Comment: If you mean could you sort the vector according to your criteria, then yes, you could. But I sense an *XY problem*.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** You can provide a custom comparator to make the underlying data get sorted another way than the default, but this only relates to *keys*, not *values*. If you have a requirement for your container's elements to exist in some specific, value-defined order, then you're using the wrong container.

You can switch to a `set`, and take advantage of the fact that there is no distinction there between "key" and "value", and hack the underlying sorting yourself:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct MyComparator
{
   typedef std::pair<int, std::vector<int>> value_type;
   bool operator()(const value_type& lhs, const value_type& rhs)
   {
      return lhs.second.at(N) < rhs.second.at(N);
   }
};

/**
 * A set of (int, int{2,}) pairs, sorted by the 2nd element in
 * the 2nd item of each pair.
 */
std::set<std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>, MyComparator<1>> my_data;

int main()
{
    my_data.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::vector<int>{0,5,0,0}));
    my_data.insert(std::make_pair(2, std::vector<int>{0,2,0,0}));
    my_data.insert(std::make_pair(3, std::vector<int>{0,1,0,0}));
    my_data.insert(std::make_pair(4, std::vector<int>{0,9,0,0}));

    for (const auto& el : my_data)
        std::cout << el.first << ' ';
}

// Output: 3 2 1 4
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/391f8092eb08dee4))

However, if you still need to perform lookup on key *as well*, then you're really in trouble and need to rethink some things. You may need to duplicate your data or provide an indexing vector.

Comment: Might be a silly question to clear my doubt, nevertheless: `unordered_map` and `map` are just implementation details leaking in C++'s implementation of the data structure called `map` which is inherently unordered, is that right?

Comment: @legends2k: I'm not sure how many would agree with me here but, IMO, yes. I think the name `unordered_map` is misleading. `unsorted_map` might make a little more sense. But I could be getting this the wrong way around as has been known to happen.

Comment: @Erbureth: Map is required to be sorted by the fact that computers have linearly increasing memory addresses, and because of how tree algorithms work. Yes, the standard asserts that requirement. Please read the _whole_ answer _carefully_ and notice the difference between "sorted" and "ordered", which is significant.

Comment: @Erbureth: Maps are _absolutely_ stored in a linear fashion, as is *every single piece of data in your computer*. That they're not stored _contiguously_ is a different thing. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to get at.

Comment: @legends2k: What does element number have to do with it? You're entirely missing my point, which is that every piece of data in your computer is found along a straight line of addresses. By that token, every piece of data in your computer is linearly sorted in some manner with respect to other pieces of data. We haven't invented 3D memory addressing yet!

Comment: @Erbureth: What? Nobody said that the standard doesn't enforce it. Of course the standard enforces it. The standard enforces many different things. It is describing the basic fundamental requirements of the type, and these requirements come from the way the tree algorithm works, which in turn is dependent on how the universe works. What is the point that you are trying to make?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit aah I see what you mean, what 3D, we haven't ventured into 2D memory yet in that sense

Comment: @legends2k: "unordered_map and map are just implementation details leaking in C++'s implementation of the data structure called map which is inherently unordered" - not at all... `map` *is inherently* ordered - a `map`'s API is specifically designed to make use of the sorted order, not just in guaranteed in-order iteration, but also in `lower_bound` et al, insertion hints for speed etc..  You could say that being a balanced binary tree is an implementation detail, but given the big-O efficiency requirements there's limited freedom for other implementations.

Comment: @TonyD I was mentioning not `std::map` but just `map` as an abstract data structure, in a mathematical sense, if you'll.

Comment: @Erbureth: No. No, it is not.

Comment: @TonyD: `std::map` is but the notion "map" that it implements is not. It's a big abstraction leak that, yes, is kinda necessary, but an abstraction leak nonetheless. The abstraction shouldn't care that there would be no other way to do it any more than it should care about how it's done. Regardless, the point is that taking a value and going "I want to slot it in <here> in my map" is wrong and bad; the OP seems to have wanted this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The `std::vector` template takes a comparator now?

Comment: @legends2k: oh ok - in as much as "map" is a shorthand for "associative container", then yes you could consider whether or not it's sorted, or implemented using hashes or a tree, as implementation detail....

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you can (build) add elements to the map the following way

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int>::size_type n = 2;

mymap[v[n]] = v;
```

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    std::srand( ( unsigned )time( 0 ) );
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::vector<int> v( N );
        std::generate( v.begin(), v.end(), []{ return std::rand() % N; } );
        m[v[0]] = v;
    }

    for ( auto &p : m )
    {
        for ( int x : p.second ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 7 8 1 2 9 0 0 9 
1 6 3 1 3 5 0 3 1 5 
3 8 0 0 0 7 1 2 9 7 
5 9 5 0 7 1 2 0 6 3 
6 4 7 5 4 0 0 4 2 0 
7 9 8 6 5 5 9 9 4 5 
8 3 8 0 5 9 6 6 8 3 
9 5 4 7 4 0 3 5 1 9
```

Take into account that as there can be duplicated vectors (that is that have the same value of the n-th element (in my example n is equal to 0) then some vectors will not be added to the map. If you want to have duplicates then you should use for example `std::multimap`

Also you can build a new map according to the criteria based on an existent map.

Comment: I thought of this too, but what if the `key` the OP has is non-trivial?

Comment: And what about duplicates? This is not just sorting that you're performing.

Comment: @legends2k He already described his map as map<int,vector<int>> mymap;

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit There is no any problem with duplicates. If you want to have duplicates then you should use std::multimap.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but we don't know what the `int` part is currently

Comment: @legends2k I showed approach how to build a map based on an element of vectors. If some map already exists then you can build another map according the requirement. I showed how it can be done.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Then you should make that part of your answer. Your answer, as it stands now, is at best incomplete and at worst flat-out wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I didn't downvote you but the issue with the answer is that say if we've 3 vectors: `{1, 5, 7}, {1, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5}` then the above code would only store the first vector, since according to it the remaining two are just duplicates, which is not true.

Comment: @legends2k I said about this in my post. In this case he should use std::multimap.

Answer (score 0):

> `map<int,vector<int>> mymap;`
>
> How can i sort this map according to the nth value of the vector contained by map?

That's only possible if you're prepared to use that n<sup>th</sup> value as the integer key too, as in consistently assigning:

```
mymap[v[n - 1]] = v;
```

If you're doing that, you might consider a `set<vector<int>>`, which removes the redundant storage of that "key" element - you would then need to provide a custom comparison though....

If you envisage taking an existing populated map that doesn't have that ordering, then sorting its elements - that's totally impossible.  You'll have to copy the elements out to another container, such as a `set` that's ordered on the n<sup>th</sup> element, or a `vector` that you `std::sort` after populating.

Answer (score -1):

You can abuse the fact a c++ map uses a tree sorted by its keys. This means that you can either create a new map, with as keys the values you wish it to be sorted on, but you can also create a `vector` with references to the items in your map, and sort that vector (or the other way around: you could have a sorted vector, and use a `map` to create an index on your vector). Be sure to use a `multimap` in the case of duplicate keys.

Comment: `A map has no predefined underlying sortedness` Well that's just wrong :) They have no overlying ordering, though.