# How can I sort a vector according to a property of its values?

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a vector of pairs

```
vector<pair<int,vector<int>>> myvector;
```

How can I sort this vector according to nth element of its inner vector?

My [previously-asked question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24241285/560648) contains the answer of sorting a vector of pairs according to a second element of the pair by using a pre-defined *sorting_function()* as below. However, in this case, I have no idea what the form of *sorting_function()* should be...

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sorting_function());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may re-use the comparator from my answer to your previous question; `sort` expects an *instance* of it, so pass in a temporary one:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), MyComparator<1>());
```

So, here's the full example:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct MyComparator
{
   typedef std::pair<int, std::vector<int>> value_type;
   bool operator()(const value_type& lhs, const value_type& rhs)
   {
      return lhs.second.at(N) < rhs.second.at(N);
   }
};

/**
 * A set of (int, int{2,}) pairs, sorted by the 2nd element in
 * the 2nd item of each pair.
 */
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>> my_data;

int main()
{
    my_data.push_back(std::make_pair(1, std::vector<int>{0,5,0,0}));
    my_data.push_back(std::make_pair(2, std::vector<int>{0,2,0,0}));
    my_data.push_back(std::make_pair(3, std::vector<int>{0,1,0,0}));
    my_data.push_back(std::make_pair(4, std::vector<int>{0,9,0,0}));

    std::sort(my_data.begin(), my_data.end(), MyComparator<1>());

    for (const auto& el : my_data)
        std::cout << el.first << ' ';
}

// Output: 3 2 1 4
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06a832ea15221425))

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. However, it still requires a constant expression. Is there any way to put a variable for the comparator?

Actually, the main problem is that i need to sort the values of outer vector with such a hierarchy that needs to sweep all values of the inner vector.

Comment: @user3744394: Yes; dump the template for `MyComparator` and make `N` a constructor argument; then: `MyComparator(1)`. This is fairly basic stuff; which C++ book are you using?

Comment: I am studying via online tutorials. This is my first few days with <vector> and similar standard template library features.

Comment: @user3744394: Oh, no! Learn from a good book. Online tutorials vary wildly in quality and accuracy, and can tell you _anything_ without you being any the wiser.

Comment: Should I change it like that?

struct MyComparator
{
 int N;
 MyComparator(int initN)
 {
  N=initN;
 }
   typedef std::pair<int, std::vector<int>> value_type;
   bool operator()(const value_type& lhs, const value_type& rhs)
   {
      return lhs.second.at(N) > rhs.second.at(N);
   }
};

Comment: @user3744394: I'd make the member `const`, and member initialisation lists are better than assignment in the constructor body, and the member should probably be called `n` (lowercase) now, and you accidentally wrote `>` instead of `<` but, otherwise, yes.

Comment: I need to sort it with decreasing order actually. I tried to sort as: sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), MyComparator(i)); but the compiler gives an error: "expects 3 arguments - 4 provided". Where the error would be? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
struct comparator
{
    comparator (int n) : n(n) { }

    typedef std::pair<int, std::vector<int>> key_type;

    bool operator() (key_type const & k1, key_type const & k2)
    {
        return k1.second[n] < k2.second[n];
    }

    int n;
};
```

I have no idea where you want 'n' to come from, but basicly that's it. Also you should put bounds checking in it.

Then you can sort your array this way:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparator(n));
```

Comment: Vectors don't have "keys" so `key_type` is a misnomer

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit key_type has nothing to do with vectors, it's the comparator's compared key type

Comment: Well okay I suppose that's arguable. It has _everything_ to do with vectors when it's the element type of the vector you're sorting, but you're right that the comparator shouldn't have to know anything about that.

Comment: @lisyarus: std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparator(n)); line gives an error: "expects 3 arguments - 4 provided". How would I solve it? Thanks...